# Getting Firebase firestore error in expo RN

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

When trying to add a collection to my firestore:

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
const UserInfo = firestore().collection("UserInfo");
```

Im receiving this error:

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on
> your Android project by calling firebase.app().
>
> Ensure you have:
>
> 1. imported the
>    'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in
>    your 'MainApplication.java' file.
> 2. Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the
>    RN 'getPackages()' method list.
>
> See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

Im using expo, so i'm not able to open the MainApplication.java file of this tutorial. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happend because i was using the firebase 9 version on the config, but was using a previous version on the code.